# How to extract values from a python dictionary and use it in a function?

Tags: python, dictionary, iteration

help is much appreciated!
In python, I want to access the values only of specific keys in a dictionary and use them in a function.

This is an example of the dictionary that I have:

`dict={'key1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'key2': ['d', 'e', 'f'], 'key3': ['g', 'h', 'i']}`

All of the lists have the same length. In real, the total length of the lists are > 800, so I don´t want to access each value manually.

This is the function that takes in two variables:

`def function(variable1, variable2) ... returnValue`

variable1 and variable2 correspond to the values from the keys in the dictionary.

This is what I want to do:
For key1 and key3 take the first value and use them as variable1 and variable2 in the function (and write the returnValue somewhere).
Then take the second values from key1 and key3 and use them as variable1 and variable2 in the function.
And so on until the very last values are used.

Seems simple, but I got stuck somehow :/

I have tried a for loop to access the elements but I´m getting Value Errors and I have tried to convert the dict into pandas Dataframe but still doesn´t work

Comment: Where is your attempt?

Comment: Check [`zip()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to iterate over pairs of items from two lists.

Comment: Hopefully the answer is helpful. Thoroughly answering questions is time-consuming. If your question is **solved**, please _**accept** the solution_. The **✔** is below the **▲/▼** arrow, at the top left of the answer. A new solution can be accepted if a better one shows up. You may also vote on the usefulness of an answer with the **▲/▼** arrow, if you have a 15+ reputation. **Leave a comment if a solution doesn't answer the question.** [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correctly, you're probably looking for [`zip`](https://docs.python.org/3.12/library/functions.html#zip), which lets you iterate over iterables in pairs (or triples, or more):

```
d = {'key1': ['a', 'b', 'c'], 'key2': ['d', 'e', 'f'], 'key3': ['g', 'h', 'i']}


def function(k1, k2):
    for v1, v2 in zip(d[k1], d[k2]):
        print(v1 + v2)  # you'd probably do something else

function('key1', 'key3')
```

prints out

```
ag
bh
ci
```